# Composing streams with flatmap in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Let's consider I have the following class:

```
class A {
   int i, j, k;

   public A(int i, int j, int k) {
     this.i = i; this.j = j; this.k = k;
   }
}
```

where `i`, `j`, `k` have a known range: `r_i`, `r_j`, `r_k`. Now I want to to generate
all possible instances of `A` in this range. I could come up with something like:

```
Stream.iterate(0, n -> ++n).limit(r_i)
.flatMap(i -> Stream.iterate(0, n -> ++n).limit(r_j)
.flatMap(j -> Stream.iterate(0, n -> ++n).limit(r_k)
.map(k -> new A(i, j, k)))).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

First, it's too verbose. Is there a way to shorten it? In particular I couldn't find a `range`
on `Stream`. Second, the compiler cannot determine the type of the returned type. It considers it as
`List<Object>` instead of the expected `List<A>`. How can I fix that?

Comment: You might want to look at `IntStream.range` to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried and it has other problems. The flatMap there doesn't allow arbitrary return type, only integer. There is an awkward mapToObj method, but I haven't found flatmapToObj.

Comment: Right. It pains me to see Java streams being awkward when LINQ in C# makes this sort of thing so simple :(

Comment: This can definitely be done with `IntStream.range` and `mapToObj` at the end. Are you sure your compiler complains or is it just your IDE? I just copied your code in IntelliJ IDEA 14 and it does not show any warnings or errors or any sort.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Have you tried List<A> = my code? It cannot infer that the result should be List<A>. About `IntStream.range`, the problem is that there should be a `flatMapToObj` or something. Can you try with `mapToObj` only and show me the code?

Comment: @Ali I definitely did and it worked like a charm. I am using Java 8 Build 20 and IntelliJ 14.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo yes, you're right. It looks like IntelliJ can infer it, but Eclipse can't. How about `IntStream.range`, could you get that running?

Comment: @Ali Yes, I could make it work too. It is not a matter of type inference. The Java compiler does pretty well, but many IDEs are full of bugs in this area. Intellij 14 when it was just released had a lot of problems in this area and with every new release they have been improving a lot. Developers have been working on their own IDE type inference algorithms, I suppose, trying to emulate, as best as they can, what the compiler does. But chances are that there are still bugs here and there. With time, this will get better, but you should ultimate trust your compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo can you please post your version with `range`? I'm curious.

Answer (score 6):

One way of using `range` is to perform a boxing conversion right afterwards:

```
List<A> list=IntStream.range(0, r_i).boxed()
  .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, r_j).boxed()
    .flatMap(j -> IntStream.range(0, r_k)
      .mapToObj(k -> new A(i, j, k)))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It’s not the most beautiful code but `IntStream.range(0, max).boxed()` is still better than `Stream.iterate(0, n -> n+1).limit(max)`…

---

One alternative is to use a real flattening operation rather than nested operations:

```
List<A> list=IntStream.range(0, r_i).boxed()
  .flatMap(i  -> IntStream.range(0, r_j).mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i,j}))
  .flatMap(ij -> IntStream.range(0, r_k).mapToObj(k -> new A(ij[0], ij[1], k)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The main drawback I see is that it suffers from the absence of an `IntPair` or `Tuple<int,int>` type. So it uses an array as a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

if it's ok to have mutable variable, you could get the List of class A like this....

```
List<A> newCollect = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, r_i).forEach(
    i -> IntStream.range(0, r_j).forEach(
        j -> IntStream.range(0, r_k).forEach(
            k -> newCollect.add(new A(i, j, k))
        )
    )
);
```

or you can make List of List of List of A, then flatMap twice like this...

```
List<A> newCollect2 = IntStream.range(0, r_i).mapToObj(
    i -> IntStream.range(0, r_j).mapToObj(
        j -> IntStream.range(0, r_k).mapToObj(
            k -> new A(i, j, k)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList())
)
.flatMap(a -> a.stream())
.flatMap(a -> a.stream())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```