# When and how to perform one to 0..n mapping Stream mapMulti over flatMap

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap, java-17, mapmulti

I have been skimming through the news and the source code of the newest LTE Java 17 version and I have encountered with new Stream method called `mapMulti`. The early-access [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) says it is similar to `flatMap`.

```
<R> Stream<R> mapMulti(BiConsumer<? super T,? super Consumer<R>> mapper)
```

- How to perform one to 0..n mapping using this method?
- How does the new method work and how does it differ from `flatMap`. When is each one preferable?
- How many times the `mapper` can be called?

Comment: By the first looks of it, looks like an overload of `flatMap`, but they must have had reasons to not overload. Then, I am glad that I am not the only one naming APIs poorly. Bookmarking this to try it out and understand, what stopped them to improve the performance with the existing combination of `filter.map` or `flatMap` instead of providing a new API. Thanks for sharing anyway.

Comment: @Naman After experimenting with this feature, I have decided to post this Q&A. I consider to do a benchmark for `filter.map` against `mapMulti`.

Comment: I think this method will fit perfectly with pattern matching, once it's more advanced than just `instanceof`

Comment: @fps: Exactly! This scenario is both presented in the [JavaDoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) (the first example) and at the **Filter-map scenario** of my answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Stream::mapMulti` is a new method that is classified as an *intermediate operation*.

It requires a `BiConsumer<T, Consumer<R>> mapper` of the element about to be processed a `Consumer`. The latter makes the method look strange at the first glance because it is different from what we are used to at the other intermediate methods such as `map`, `filter`, or `peek` where none of them use any variation of `*Consumer`.

The purpose of the `Consumer` provided right within the lambda expression by the API itself is to accept *any* number elements to be available in the subsequent pipeline. Therefore, all the elements, regardless of how many, will be propagated.

#### Explanation using simple snippets

- **One to some (0..1) mapping** (similar to `filter`)

  Using the `consumer.accept(R r)` for only a few selected items achieves filter-alike pipeline. This might get useful in case of checking the element against a predicate *and* it's mapping to a different value, which would be otherwise done using a combination of `filter` and `map` instead. The following

  ```java
  Stream.of("Java", "Python", "JavaScript", "C#", "Ruby")
        .mapMulti((str, consumer) -> {
            if (str.length() > 4) {
                consumer.accept(str.length());  // lengths larger than 4
            }
        })
        .forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));

  // 6 10
  ```
- **One to one mapping** (similar to `map`)

  Working with the previous example, when the condition is omitted and *every* element is mapped into a new one and accepted using the `consumer`, the method effectively behaves like `map`:

  ```java
  Stream.of("Java", "Python", "JavaScript", "C#", "Ruby")
        .mapMulti((str, consumer) -> consumer.accept(str.length()))
        .forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));

  // 4 6 10 2 4
  ```
- **One to many mapping** (similar to `flatMap`)

  Here things get interesting because one can call `consumer.accept(R r)` *any* number of times. Let's say we want to replicate the number representing the String length by itself, i.e. `2` becomes `2`, `2`. `4` becomes `4`, `4`, `4`, `4`. and `0` becomes nothing.

  ```java
  Stream.of("Java", "Python", "JavaScript", "C#", "Ruby", "")
        .mapMulti((str, consumer) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                consumer.accept(str.length());
            }
        })
        .forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));

  // 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 2 2 4 4 4 4
  ```

#### Comparison with flatMap

The very idea of this mechanism is that is can be called multiple times (including zero) and its usage of `SpinedBuffer` internally allows to *push* the elements into a single flattened Stream instance without creating a new one for every group of output elements unlike `flatMap`. The [JavaDoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) states **two** use-cases when using this method is preferable over `flatMap`:

> - When replacing each stream element with a small (possibly zero) number of elements. Using this method avoids the overhead of creating a new Stream instance for every group of result elements, as required by flatMap.
> - When it is easier to use an imperative approach for generating result elements than it is to return them in the form of a Stream.

Performance-wise, the new method `mapMulti` is a winner in such cases. Check out the benchmark at the bottom of this answer.

#### Filter-map scenario

Using this method instead of `filter` or `map` separately doesn't make sense due to its verbosity and the fact one intermediate stream is created anyway. The exception might be replacing the `.filter(..).map(..)` chain *called together*, which comes handy in the case such as checking the element type and its casting.

```java
int sum = Stream.of(1, 2.0, 3.0, 4F, 5, 6L)
                .mapMultiToInt((number, consumer) -> {
                    if (number instanceof Integer) {
                        consumer.accept((Integer) number);
                    }
                })
                .sum();
// 6
```

```java
int sum = Stream.of(1, 2.0, 3.0, 4F, 5, 6L)
                .filter(number -> number instanceof Integer)
                .mapToInt(number -> (Integer) number)
                .sum();
```

As seen above, its variations like [`mapMultiToDouble`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMultiToDouble(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), [`mapMultiToInt`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMultiToInt(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) and [`mapMultiToLong`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMultiToLong(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) were introduced. This comes along the `mapMulti` methods within the primitive Streams such as [`IntStream mapMulti​(IntStream.IntMapMultiConsumer mapper)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapMulti(java.util.stream.IntStream.IntMapMultiConsumer)). Also, three new functional interfaces were introduced. Basically, they are the primitive variations of `BiConsumer<T, Consumer<R>>`, example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface IntMapMultiConsumer {
    void accept(int value, IntConsumer ic);
}
```

#### Combined real use-case scenario

The real power of this method is in its flexibility of usage and creating only one Stream at a time, which is the major advantage over `flatMap`. The two below snippets represent a flatmapping of `Product` and its `List<Variation>` into `0..n` offers represented by the `Offer` class and based on certain conditions (product category and the variation availability).

- `Product` with `String name`, `int basePrice`, `String category` and `List<Variation> variations`.
- `Variation` with `String name`, `int price` and `boolean availability`.

```java
List<Product> products = ...
List<Offer> offers = products.stream()
        .mapMulti((product, consumer) -> {
            if ("PRODUCT_CATEGORY".equals(product.getCategory())) {
                for (Variation v : product.getVariations()) {
                    if (v.isAvailable()) {
                        Offer offer = new Offer(
                            product.getName() + "_" + v.getName(),
                            product.getBasePrice() + v.getPrice());
                        consumer.accept(offer);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
List<Product> products = ...
List<Offer> offers = products.stream()
        .filter(product -> "PRODUCT_CATEGORY".equals(product.getCategory()))
        .flatMap(product -> product.getVariations().stream()
            .filter(Variation::isAvailable)
            .map(v -> new Offer(
                product.getName() + "_" + v.getName(),
                product.getBasePrice() + v.getPrice()
            ))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The use of `mapMulti` is more imperatively inclined compared to the declarative approach of the previous-versions Stream methods combination seen in the latter snippet using `flatMap`, `map`, and `filter`. From this perspective, it depends on the use-case whether is easier to use an imperative approach. Recursion is a good example described in the [JavaDoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

#### Benchmark

As promised, I have wrote a bunch of micro-benchmarks from ideas collected from the comments. As long as there is quite a lot of code to publish, I have created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/java-16-mapmulti-benchmark) with the implementation details and I am about to share the results only.

**`Stream::flatMap(Function)` vs `Stream::mapMulti(BiConsumer)`** [Source](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/java-16-mapmulti-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nichar/java16/benchmark/MapMulti_FlatMap.java)

Here we can see the huge difference and a proof the newer method actually works as described and its usage avoid the overhead of creating a new Stream instance with each processed element.

```
Benchmark                                   Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MapMulti_FlatMap.flatMap                    avgt   25  73.852 ± 3.433  ns/op
MapMulti_FlatMap.mapMulti                   avgt   25  17.495 ± 0.476  ns/op
```

**`Stream::filter(Predicate).map(Function)` vs `Stream::mapMulti(BiConsumer)`** [Source](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/java-16-mapmulti-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nichar/java16/benchmark/MapMulti_FilterMap.java)

Using chained pipelines (not nested, though) is fine.

```
Benchmark                                   Mode  Cnt    Score  Error  Units
MapMulti_FilterMap.filterMap                avgt   25   7.973 ± 0.378  ns/op
MapMulti_FilterMap.mapMulti                 avgt   25   7.765 ± 0.633  ns/op
```

**`Stream::flatMap(Function)` with `Optional::stream()` vs `Stream::mapMulti(BiConsumer)`** [Source](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/java-16-mapmulti-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nichar/java16/benchmark/MapMulti_FlatMap_Optional.java)

This one is very interesting, escpecially in terms of usage (see the source code): we are now able to flatten using `mapMulti(Optional::ifPresent)` and as expected, the new method is a bit faster in this case.

```
Benchmark                                   Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MapMulti_FlatMap_Optional.flatMap           avgt   25  20.186 ± 1.305  ns/op
MapMulti_FlatMap_Optional.mapMulti          avgt   25  10.498 ± 0.403  ns/op
```

Comment: Interesting. Suddenly, there’s a simple(r) way to turn arbitrary non-collection objects that support `Consumer` into a stream. E.g., an already existing `Iterator`. But also converting a stream of `CompletionStage` instances into a stream of results simplified to `mapMulti(CompletionStage::thenAccept)`…

Comment: The `SpinnedBuffer` is only in the default implementation, `ReferencePipeline` overrides that and "exposes" the actual `Sink` (elements are consumed by this), which is what that `consumer` is. This is rather crazy, never thought about it this way.

Comment: @Eugene I suppose, a buffer still comes into play when the terminal operation is short-circuiting whereas the actual sink can be passed directly for the others.

Comment: A case worth benchmarking, is the processing of a stream of `Optional`, i.e. `flatMap(Optional::stream)` vs. `mapMulti(Optional::ifPresent)`. Only the limited type inference is annoying. It seems, we almost always need `.<IntendedType>mapMulti(…)`…

Comment: It’s worth running such a benchmark with different list sizes, as well as other terminal operations, to get a better picture of the actual impact of the intermediate operation.

Comment: IIRC you can turn the `COUNT` variable via annotation into a parameter that JMH can vary

Comment: @Nikolas yes. Also you could run this in multiple `@Fork`s for lower error. I have a git project that does this against github ( since it takes a lot of time multiple forks ) ...

Comment: Wow great job @NikolasCharalambidis

Answer (score 12):

To address the scenario

> When it is easier to use an imperative approach for generating result elements than it is to return them in the form of a Stream.

We can see it as now having a limited variant of [the yield statement C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39476/2711488). The limitations are that we always need an initial input from a stream, as this is an intermediate operation, further, there’s no short-circuiting for the elements we’re pushing in one function evaluation.

Still, it opens interesting opportunities.

E.g., implementing a stream of Fibonacci number formerly required [a solution using temporary objects capable of holding two values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596139/2711488).

Now, we can use something like:

```java
IntStream.of(0)
    .mapMulti((a,c) -> {
        for(int b = 1; a >=0; b = a + (a = b))
            c.accept(a);
    })
    /* additional stream operations here */
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It stops when the `int` values overflow, as said, it won’t short-circuit when we use a terminal operation that does not consume all values, however, this loop producing then-ignored values might still be faster than the other approaches.

Another example inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240859/2711488), to iterate over a class hierarchy from root to most specific:

```java
Stream.of(LinkedHashMap.class).mapMulti(MapMultiExamples::hierarchy)
    /* additional stream operations here */
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```java
static void hierarchy(Class<?> cl, Consumer<? super Class<?>> co) {
    if(cl != null) {
        hierarchy(cl.getSuperclass(), co);
        co.accept(cl);
    }
}
```

which unlike the old approaches does not require additional heap storage and will likely run faster (assuming reasonable class depths that do not make recursion backfire).

Also monsters [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27803385/2711488)

> ```
> List<A> list = IntStream.range(0, r_i).boxed()
>     .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, r_j).boxed()
>         .flatMap(j -> IntStream.range(0, r_k)
>             .mapToObj(k -> new A(i, j, k))))
>     .collect(Collectors.toList());
> ```

can now be written like

```java
List<A> list = IntStream.range(0, r_i).boxed()
    .<A>mapMulti((i,c) -> {
        for(int j = 0; j < r_j; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < r_k; k++) {
                c.accept(new A(i, j, k));
            }
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Compared to the nested `flatMap` steps, it loses some parallelism opportunity, which the reference implementation didn’t exploit anyway. For a non-short-circuiting operation like above, the new method likely will benefit from the reduced boxing and less instantiation of capturing lambda expressions. But of course, it should be used judiciously, not to rewrite every construct to an imperative version (after so many people tried to rewrite every imperative code into a functional version)…

Comment: I am impressed how fast you came with such various scenarios. IMHO the nested flatmapping is the issue when the most of the performance will be saved. On the other hand, looking at the last snippet gives me a though that as long as the method is based on the imperative approach, the whole Stream is not needed at all and the whole code would make sense with few for-each cycles.

Comment: the examples are spot on! you helped to find two cases in our coded base where we can use this, thank u.

Comment: @Nikolas of course, it depends on the subsequent stream operations or whether returning a Stream is part of the contract. When just chaining a trivial operation, an ordinary loop might indeed still be the canonical solution.