# How to replace iter loops by stream

Tags: java, spring, loops, java-stream

I am tryning to replace that code using stream.

```
public int countPenaltyPointsTest(Set<OffenceEntity> offences, LocalDate date) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (OffenceEntity offence : offences) {
        for (OffenceDetailsEntity offenceDetailsEntity : offence.getDetails()) {
            if (date.isAfter(offenceDetailsEntity.getStartDate())
                    && date.isBefore(offenceDetailsEntity.getEndDate())) {
                sum +=offenceDetailsEntity.getPenaltyPoints();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have OffenceEntity with OneToMany relationsh with OffenceDetailsEntity:

```
@Entity
public class OffenceEntity {
    ...
    private Set<OffenceDetailsEntity> details;
}


@Entity
public class OffenceDetailsEntity {
    ...
    private int penaltyPoints;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OffenceEntity offence;
}
```

and I would like to collect penalty points where date is between two dates.
I know how to do it for example when I have field like penalty points in OffenceEntity.
Example:

```
int sum = offences.stream()
            .mapToInt(OffenceEntity::getPenaltyPoints)
            .sum();
```

but I do not know how to "jump" to the set in OffenceEntity

Comment: You can use `flatMap(offence -> offence.getDetails().stream())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to flatten the stream data, i.e. turn each element of type `OffenceEntity` into a group of elements, `mapToInt()` isn't the right operation. For that purpose you can use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) (or its flavor [`flatMapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function))).

To differentiate between the two operations `map()` and `flatMap()`, remember a simple principle:

- when you need ***one-to-one** transformation*, use `map()` or it's flavors
- for ***one-to-many** transformation* - `flatMap()` or it's flavors.

Since Java 16 we can also utilize [`mapMulty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) to flatten the data in the stream. But it's rather a special purpose tool than a common option. Apart from flattening this operation allows to filter out stream elements so in contrast to `flatMap()` which turns an element into **`1+`** (*one or more*) elements, `mapMulty()` produces **`0+`** (*zero or more*) elements.

## flatMap()

`flatMap()` expects as an argument a function, that takes an element and produces a stream (*which is also important distinction between* `map` *and* `flatMap`).

After flattening stream data, we need to filter `OffenceDetailsEntity` objects having a suitable date and extract `penaltyPoints`. Which can be done using `filter()` + `mapToInt()`.

```
public int countPenaltyPointsTest(Set<OffenceEntity> offences, LocalDate date) {
    
    return offences.stream()                                // Stream<OffenceEntity>
        .flatMap(offence -> offence.getDetails().stream())  // Stream<OffenceDetailsEntity>
        .filter(ode -> date.isAfter(ode.getStartDate())     // Stream<OffenceDetailsEntity>
                        && date.isBefore(ode.getEndDate()))
        .mapToInt(OffenceDetailsEntity::getPenaltyPoints)   // IntStream
        .sum();
}
```

## mapMulty()

This operation allows incorporating imperative programming features (*i.e. loops and conditional statements*) into the stream pipeline.

As mentioned before, it's a *special purpose tool* with a lot of peculiarities which should be applied mindfully.

Here's quote from the [API Note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) regurding when to use `mapMulty()`:

> This method is preferable to `flatMap` in the following circumstances:
>
> - When replacing each stream element with a **small** (*possibly zero*) number of elements. Using this method avoids the overhead of creating
>   a new `Stream` instance for every group of result elements, as required
>   by `flatMap`.
> - When it is **easier to use** an **imperative approach** for generating result elements than it is to return them in the form of a `Stream`.

For instance, `mapMulty()` is capable to substitute a combination `flatMap()` + `filter()`, or multiple `flatMap()` operations.

It expects an argument of type `BiConsumer`, i.e. a consumer, which in turn takes *two arguments*: *stream element* and a *consumer* of the resulting type. Each value offered to the consumer becomes a new stream element, replacing the initial element.

Here's how this method can be implemented using `mapMultyToInt()`:

```
public int countPenaltyPointsTest(Set<OffenceEntity> offences, LocalDate date) {
    
    return offences.stream()
        .mapMultiToInt((offence, consumer) -> 
            offence.getDetails().forEach(ode -> {
                if (date.isAfter(ode.getStartDate()) && date.isBefore(ode.getEndDate()))
                    consumer.accept(ode.getPenaltyPoints());
        }))
        .sum();
}
```

For more examples and information on how to use `mapMulty()`, have a look at [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132803/when-and-how-to-perform-one-to-0-n-mapping-stream-mapmulti-over-flatmap).

Comment: Thank you, I think I coulde be close to do it if i used flatMapToInt.

Comment: @Lulex97 The principle is simple: when you need one-to-one transformation - use `map()` or it's flavors. For one-to-many `flatMap()` or it's flavors.