# Proper way of concatenating lists with single elements in a single logical line in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

In my code, I have this :

```java
    private static final List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        addAll(b);
        addAll(c);
        add(d);
        add(e);
    }};
```

I read in some places that the double-braces syntax creates an anonymous class or something and that it's a very bad syntax.

As this is a static final variable, it needs to be set in a single logical line.

I found examples of code concatenating lists in a single line using a stream, but none that allow for individual elements to be added.

I'm looking for a syntax that would be compatible with Java 8, but (if different) a better syntax only compatible with later versions of Java would be welcome too.

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>(List.of(a,b,c,d,e));` or alternatively (a way to avoid the double brace syntax) declare `private static final List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();` then use a static initializer block to init some values

Comment: You can use `Stream.concat(b.stream(), c.stream(), Stream.of(d), Stream.of(e)).toList()`, but Holger's answer is cleaner IMO.

Comment: Obligatory _"dont use the double-brace antipattern"_. Many users dont understand its implications and that its not just _"a neat little syntax trick"_. It creates an anonymous class and then utilizes an initializer block in that class to add custom code (similar to a constructor). While technically not dangerous in this particular example, it can lead to serious issues on more complex scenarios.

With the addition of shorthands like `List.of(...)` and similar, its also not really needed anymore to create compact code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no requirement for a `static final` variable to be initialized in a “single logical line”.

You can simply write

```
private static final List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
static {
    a.addAll(b);
    a.addAll(c);
    a.add(d);
    a.add(e);
}
```

which is called a static initializer block.

---

Note that since this list will stay mutable the entire runtime, you can add to the list at any time and any place.

Since you probably do not want this, but rather a truly immutable list initialized with the class, you can even write

```
private static final List<String> a;
static {
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.addAll(b);
    tmp.addAll(c);
    tmp.add(d);
    tmp.add(e);
    a = List.copyOf(tmp);
}
```

in other words, assign the field at the end of the initializer block with the final result.

`List.copyOf(…)` (since Java 9) creates an immutable copy but does not allow `null` elements and has a [very strict behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) regarding `null` in general.

If you need an unmodifiable list with null support, you can use [`tmp.stream().toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) (since Java 16).

---

But even for those who don’t know about static initializers, there is a very simple solution for complex field initializers:

```
private static final List<String> a = createA();

private static List<String> createA() {
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.addAll(b);
    tmp.addAll(c);
    tmp.add(d);
    tmp.add(e);
    return List.copyOf(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What do you mean by "it does not allow null" : the list cannot contain null, or copyOf only takes non-null lists ? Also, I have several of such fields, I can use one static block per variable right ? And nothing of this changes in a big way if I switch to using Set ?

Comment: The list returned by `List.copyOf(…)` does not allow `null` elements and even throws when you try `contains(null)`. If you need `null` support, you can use `tmp.stream().toList()` (with recent Java versions). You can have as many initializer blocks as you like, but you can also write the code for multiple variables in one block. It’s up to you. And yes, it works for all kind of objects, including `Set`s.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. I think the null infos would gain by being added in the answer body, but I'm accepting it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stream API if you want a one-liner:

```java
private static final List<String> a = Stream.of(b, c, List.of(d), List.of(e))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As of JDK 16+ there is `mapMulti` that allows avoiding excessive flat-mapping (I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132804/3764965) explaining more details):

```java
private static final List<String> a = Stream.of(b, c, List.of(d), List.of(e))
        .<String>mapMulti(Iterable::forEach)
        .toList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I Think the other one is more elegant and most likely faster, but yours has the advantage of being a true one-liner.