# Are there any drawbacks in merging collections with Stream.concat()?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

The goal: to merge two collections into (a third) one

I like the fluency of this solution (it only takes one statement):

```java
Stream.concat(collection.stream(), anotherCollection.stream())
    .collect(/* some Collector */)
```

However, my latest PR commit, though accepted and merged, was edited to replace that line with this (notice there are now twice as many statements):

```java
Collection</* some type */> mergedCollection = new /* Collection implementation */<>(collection);

mergedCollection.addAll(anotherCollection);
```

I don't want to bother the maintainer who made the change so I decided to ask the SO community:

Are there any drawbacks in merging collections with `Stream.concat()`?

Comment: There are twice as many statements but only one method call. Yours has four.

Comment: And the person who changed your commit should certainly have provided a reason, and if he hasn’t he should be made to.

Comment: To put it in one statement: your approach using `concat` is fine, but the approach using collection constructor + `addAll` may be even faster, depending on the actual collection type(s).

Answer (score 3):

Its main disadvantage to using `Stream#concat` is it only accepts 2 streams. It does what it says: concatenates two streams together into one.

If you need to concatenate three or more streams, use `Stream#of`, however, it comes with flat mapping:

```java
final List<Object> list = Stream.of(collection1, collection2, collection3)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .toList();
```

Flat mapping itself is not bad but relies on a stream's existence for the concatenation. It is not ideal if there are a lot of nested structures as the result is an unnecessary number of streams created temporarily only for flat mapping and the performance might be hit with larger numbers.

**What to do?** The best option is `Stream#mapMulti` to avoid excessive creation of additional streams:

```java
final List<Object> list = Stream.of(collection1, collection2, collection3)
    .mapMulti(Collection::forEach)
    .toList();
```

To understand it better, here is the expanded notation using a lambda expression instead of a method reference:

```java
final List<Object> list = Stream.of(collection1, collection2, collection3)
    .mapMulti((collection, consumer) -> collection.forEach(consumer))
    .toList();
```

This was invented as of Java 16 and I wrote another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132803/when-and-how-to-perform-one-to-0-n-mapping-stream-mapmulti-over-flatmap/64132804#64132804) regarding its use.

Comment: It’s not a ‘main disadvantage’ any more than it is for `addAll()`. You can always call `concat()` or `addAll()` again …

Comment: It's the main disadvantage as it's the only disadvantage (it'd be nice if it allowed more streams to be concatenated and the flat mapping were handled internally). If you know another disadvantage, speak it up rather than clinging to words.

Comment: You need a very large number of collections before running into the problem of “excessive creation of additional streams”. As a rule of thumb, if you can name all of them in a `Stream.of(…)` call, the number of elements is not excessive. But more importantly you didn’t address the OP’s actual concern. The alternative, their code was replaced with, is not discussed in your answer at all.

Comment: It’s *not* a disadvantage, because there is nothing to compare it to that doesn’t have that disadvantage. You can’t pass two parameters to `addAll()`., or `mapMulti()`. But you can call them all twice. Or more.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Holger in a comment, both approaches are fine, but the second one may give substantial performance benefits, if it matters for them.

Indeed, when the `Stream` approach copies elements one by one through the collection process, most `Collection` implementations have optimized `addAll()` implementations.

For example, `ArrayList` will do everything through `System.arraycopy()`, a native call that will typically rely on pure memory operations.

Comment: In case of `ArrayList`, the constructor + `addAll` approach also guarantees that there’s exactly one capacity increment operation, in contrast to repeatedly `add` an element to an `ArrayList` created with default capacity.

Comment: @Holger yes, I didn’t want to dive too much in the implementation details since the question does not specify which collection type is used